# Is there any way to brighten up maps?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I've already set my gamma up to the highest setting, but on my screen (glossy), the maps are so dark as to be almost unviewable - all I can see are the markers, and sometimes brighter areas or tracks.

Is there a way to make maps more legible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue that may be patched in the future, [according to a dev on the obsidian forums](http://forums.obsidian.net/topic/72004-local-area-map-incredibly-darkdifficult-to-see/?p=1603769):

> We currently darken areas of the map that are beyond the line of sight of your characters. I do agree though that the inconvenience not being able to see the map clearly far out weights the value of line of sight radius information. I'll bring this up and see if we can fix in patch.